# How does Star-Lord's Helmet work?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy

What are its capabilities? How does it function? Where did it originate?

Answers from both the comics and movies are acceptable, but please keep in mind to detail which universe you are answering for, and note the difference between them.

Information from comics is preferred, but not absolutely necessary.

Comment: You know you've been in design too long when you read that last sentence as "Comic sans is preferred" and almost throw your shoe through your monitor...

Comment: "Very well, thank you..." -typical response

Comment: http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Star-Lord's_Helmet and http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Peter_Quill_(Earth-616)#Equipment are obvious places to start.